# Codeigniter Table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a project that requires for me to display all the data in one column. The table should be 2 columns with 7 rows down one column will have data from database and other will have check boxes to be checked.

How can I make a table like this? I tried using template in an array and then load it with:

```
$this->table->set_template($tmp1);
```

but it doesn't work, it's still displaying everything in one row.

Here is my code:

view.php

```
<body> 
    <h1>Answer</h1>
    <div id="pagination">

<?php echo $this->table->generate($records);?>


<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

controller.php

```
 function index()
       {            
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('table');          
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/survey/index';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('save_survey')->num_rows();

        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
      //print_r($this->uri->segment());die;

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survey', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3, 0))->result_array();

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('survey_view', $data);

      }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a customized table containing checkboxes

Best way is to generate the table manually
you do this by the following

```
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('save_survay', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3, 0))->result_array();
foreach($data['records'] as  $record) 
{
    $this->table->add_row(
                 form_checkbox($data, $value),
                 $record['col1'],
                 $record['col2']
    )
}
```

and do not forget to set the headings yourself as well

```
 $this->table->set_heading('h1','h2',...etc)
```